# CiviContribute Component Settings not saving settings beyond Enable Tax and Invoicing option

Tags: civicontribute, error, settings

I am setting up a fresh install (CiviCRM 5.24.5 / WordPress 5.4.1) but found that once I 'Enable Tax and Invoicing' within CiviContribute Component Settings no changes are saved on that page (I am trying to save changes to the due date, notes, tax term, and tax display settings) other than the 'Enable Tax and Invoicing' option (and I get the settings saved notification).

I am very new to this and have been working my way through using the docs (https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/contributions/sales-tax-and-vat/) and have set up Financial Account for Sales Tax/VAT just in case but to no effect.  Everything appears to be working normally.

While I want the invoicing, as a small charity we are below the VAT threshold and the VAT rate is set to zero, though setting to 20 makes no difference in the VAT/Sales Tax Financial Account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is a regression: follow along here (and do report you're seeing this as well): https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/1712

And it has been fixed (missed closing it).

You will want to upgrade your CiviCRM to either 5.24.6 or 5.25.0 (we're not sure when the fix went in).

Comment: Many thanks, upgrading to 5.25.0 fixed it.